# How to export computers from Active Directory to XML using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, remote-desktop

I am trying to create a powershell scripts for Remote Desktop Connection Manager using the active directory module.

My first thought was get a list of computers in AD and parse them out into XML format similar to the OU structure that is in AD. I have no problem with that, the below code will work just but not how I wanted.

```
EG # here is a the array $OUs

Americas/Canada/Canada Computers/Desktops
Americas/Canada/Canada Computers/Laptops
Americas/Canada/Canada Computers/Virtual Computers
Americas/USA/USA Computers/Laptops
Computers
Disabled Accounts
Domain Controllers
EMEA/UK/UK Computers/Desktops
EMEA/UK/UK Computers/Laptops
Outside Sales and Service/Laptops
Servers
```

I wanted to have the basic XML structured like this

```
Americas
    Canada
        Canada Computers
            Desktops
            Laptops
            Virtual Computers
    USA
        USA Computers
            Laptops
Computers
Disabled Accounts
Domain Controllers
EMEA
    UK
        UK Computers
            Desktops
            Laptops
Outside Sales and Service
    Laptops
Servers
```

However if you run the below it does not nest the next string in the array it only restarts the from the beginning and duplicating

```
Americas
    Canada
        Canada Computers
            Desktops
Americas
    Canada
        Canada Computers
            Laptops
Americas
    Canada
        Canada Computers
            Virtual Computers
Americas
    USA
        USA Computers
            Laptops
```

RDCMGenerator.ps1

```
#Importing Microsoft`s PowerShell-module for administering ActiveDirectory 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

#Initial variables 
$OUs = @()

$RDCMVer = "2.2"
$userName = "domain\username"
$password = "Hashed Password+"
$Path = "$env:temp\test.xml"

$allComputers = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(OperatingSystem=*)" -Properties Name,Description,CanonicalName | Sort-Object CanonicalName | select Name,Description,CanonicalName
$allOUObjects = $allComputers | Foreach {"$($_.CanonicalName)"}

Function Initialize-XML{
##<RDCMan schemaVersion="1">
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('RDCMan')
    $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('schemaVersion', '1')
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('version',$RDCMVer)
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('file')
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('properties')
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('name',$env:userdomain)
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('expanded','true')
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('comment','')
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('logonCredentials')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'None')
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('userName',$userName)
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('domain',$env:userdomain)
                $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('password')
                    $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('storeAsClearText', 'false')
                    $XmlWriter.WriteRaw($password)
                $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('connectionSettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('gatewaySettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('remoteDesktop')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'None')
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('size','1024 x 768')
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('sameSizeAsClientArea','True')
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('fullScreen','False')
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('colorDepth','32')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('localResources')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('securitySettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('displaySettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()    
}
Function Create-Group ($groupName){
#Start Group
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('properties')
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('name',$groupName)
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('expanded','true')
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('comment','')
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('logonCredentials')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('connectionSettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('gatewaySettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('remoteDesktop')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('localResources')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('securitySettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('displaySettings')
                $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()    
}
Function Create-Server ($computerName, $computerDescription) {


    #Start Server
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('server')
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('name',$computerName)
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('displayName',$computerDescription)
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('comment','')
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('logonCredentials')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('connectionSettings')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('gatewaySettings')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('remoteDesktop')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('localResources')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('securitySettings')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('displaySettings')
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString('inherit', 'FromParent')
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    #Stop Server
}
Function Close-XML {
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
# finalize the document:
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()

notepad $path   
}


#Strip out Domain and Computer Name from CanonicalName
foreach($OU in $allOUObjects){
    $newSplit = $OU.split("/")
    $rebildOU = ""
    for($i=1; $i -le ($newSplit.count - 2); $i++){
        $rebildOU += $newSplit[$i] + "/"
    }   
    $OUs += $rebildOU.substring(0,($rebildOU.length - 1))
}

#Remove Duplicate OU's
$OUs = $OUs | select -uniq
#$OUs

# get an XMLTextWriter to create the XML
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($Path,$UTF8)

# choose a pretty formatting:
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"

# write the header
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
#
#   'encoding', 'utf-8' How?
#
# set XSL statements


#Initialize Pre-Defined XML
Initialize-XML

#########################################################
# Start Loop for each OU-Path that has a computer in it
#########################################################
foreach ($OU in $OUs){
    $totalGroupName = ""                            #Create / Reset Total OU-Path Completed

    $OU.split("/") | foreach {                      #Split the OU-Path into individual OU's
        $groupName = "$_"                           #Current OU
        $totalGroupName += $groupName + "/"         #Total OU-Path Completed
        $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('group')       #Start new XML Group

        Create-Group $groupName                     #Call function to create XML Group

        ################################################
        # Start Loop for each Computer in $allComputers
        ################################################
        foreach($computer in $allComputers){
            $computerOU = $computer.CanonicalName                                       #Set the computers OU-Path
            $OUSplit = $computerOU.split("/")                                           #Create the Split for the OU-Path
            $rebiltOU = ""                                                              #Create / Reset the stripped OU-Path

            for($i=1; $i -le ($OUSplit.count - 2); $i++){                               #Start Loop for OU-Path to strip out the Domain and Computer Name
                $rebiltOU += $OUSplit[$i] + "/"                                         #Rebuild the stripped OU-Path
            }
            if ($rebiltOU -eq $totalGroupName){                                         #Compare the Current OU-Path with the computers stripped OU-Path
                $computerName = $computer.Name                                          #Set the computer name
                $computerDescription = $computerName + " - " + $computer.Description    #Set the computer Description
                Create-Server $computerName $computerDescription                        #Call function to create XML Server
            }
        }
    }
    ###################################################
    # Start Loop to close out XML Groups created above
    ###################################################
    $totalGroupName.split("/") | foreach {  #Split the
        if ($_ -ne "" ){
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            #End Group
        }
    }
}               
Close-XML
```

Comment: Quick question: What *exactly* did you want the script to accomplish? You mentioned the RDC Manager but I don't see what you want it to do, besides output the machines in AD in an XML format?

Comment: The RDCManager config file is formatted in XML. Please reference http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=21101

Comment: Sorry, I forgot all about this tool. Yeah I left it alone a while back for that very reason (I didn't think about exporting from powershell at the time), +1 for the question, I'll take a look unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was migrated here. The problem is with your code, this has nothing to do with any function that is native to AD.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you're always creating a new group, inependently if this group already exists or not.

For example, in your code:

```
   $groupName = "$_"                           #Current OU
   $totalGroupName += $groupName + "/"         #Total OU-Path Completed
   $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('group')       #Start new XML Group

   Create-Group $groupName                     #Call function to create XML Group
```

you never checked if the node corresponding to the group $groupName. If your review the Create-Group function, the function itself neither do that check, so you are always creating the group.

The problem here is that the object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter, as far as I know, is intended only for writing without cache, so you should maintain a paralel structure to track group creation or change the way you are generating the XML. I usually use System.XML.XmlDocument instead. I know it's quite manual way of working with XML by my own experience is that is by far more flexible.

Hope this may help!!